# How to display custom columns data?

Tags: web-part, column, custom

I am using Office365 SharePoint, performing this on a wiki page. I have created custom columns (Business Area and Products), and would like to display the columns on the side of a publish page.

[image: Custom columns added - business area and products]

Below is what I would like to have:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new page layout with the custom field to display. 
Below is the link for creating new page layout
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of library settings check the all Documents view where you should add or remove columns as you need and make sure it's the default view.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can you provide more details? Under Settings > Create View, there doesn't seem to be anything that can help me display a sidebar with the custom column details

Comment: Check what I mean I have updated the answer and hope it helps you and don't forget upvote :)

Comment: Hi Joun, my settings are as above. But instead of All Documents, I have All Pages. And all the views are checked.